# How do I log a user out that has been manually authenticated using <asp:Login...?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I followed number 4 on [this tutorial](http://forums.asp.net/t/1403132.aspx) and am authenticating users from my own table by doing

```
protected void  Login1_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    string userName = Login1.UserName;
    string password = Login1.Password;

    // my custom user login function.
    bool result = UserLogin(userName, password);
    if ((result))
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}
```

Does this mean they have a session like regular users?

**How would I log a user out after they say change their password?**

Answer (score 0):

On each user you have two main different cookies. **One cookie is set for the session** and **one cookie/ticket is set for the authentication**.

Session and authentication are different.

To SigOut a user, as you ask you call the [`FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove the ticket from the user.

To clear the session you use the `Session.Abandon()` but is better to just reset only the variables that you have somehow connect with the login.

Because each of this functions is actually reset-clear a cookie, you better redirect after you set them, so the browser accept the cookie commands and clears them.